# Javascript won't recognize web service

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I tried to create this by following the video at http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-7026.aspx where Joe Stagner created a simple web service that is called with Ajax. In the Button1_onclick() handler, javascript can't resolve the object "WebService1". Do you see s anything wrong?

The exact error is "'WebService1' is undefined" in Button1_onclick().

Note: I took out the head and body tags so the post would display ok. They are all there in my file.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Button1_onclick() {
        ret = WebService1.HelloWorld(document.getElementById("Text1").value, OnComplete, OnError);
    }

    function OnError() {
        alert("An error occurred");
    }
    function OnComplete(arg) {
        document.getElementById("CallResponse").innerHTML = arg;
    }
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService1.asmx" />
</Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" /><br /><br />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click to test Ajax" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" /><br />
    <div id="CallResponse">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here's the web service. Yes, I un-commented the line I was supposed to.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace AjaxTest
{
    /// 
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// 
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(string s)
        {
            return "Hello " + s;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should look for `AjaxTest.WebService1` as the class. It works off the fully qualified namespace

Comment: Thank you! Stack Overflow guys are awesome.